# Data structure for Matrix lookup in ruby, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-structures

i want to use a matrix type data structure for storing and looking up values.
for this 2d array can be used. but i am looking for a better structure.

Requirements:
Matrix columns are fixed, but rows can increase.

for e.g.
see the following structure.

```
Issue| col1, col2, col3, col4
1    |   0,    1,   0,    0
2    |   0,    1,   0,    1
3    |   1,    1,   0,    0
```

[values in the structure are used as flag or status field]

now i want this structure to be used for look up

say i want to know the value for issue 2 col1 (which is 0 in above example)

what can be the better structure in ruby for the above scenario?

comments please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a hash?

```
h = { 1 => [0,1,0,0],
  2 => [0,1,0,1],
  3 => [1,1,0,0] }

#fetch value for issue 2 col 1
puts h[2][0]
```

Comment: thnx for quick reply.. can hash be a named one? say for e.g. h[2][col1] ?? the above is array of hashes where hash elements are accessible through an index value.. but how can this be used as a named hash?

Comment: i can use something like {1=>[{:col3=>0, :col4=>0, :col1=>1, :col2=>1}], 2=>[{:col1=>0}]} but in this case how to access the value .. say i want to get value for h[1][:col1]??

Comment: You could use that if you like, since the columns will be static you can just define a constant which provides the index for the column name. Something like COLUMN_INDEX = { 1 => :col1, 2 => :col2 } ; h[1][COLUMN_INDEX[:col1]].   It doesn't look pretty though. Anything more complicated than that I would put into a class

Answer (score 1):

In case your data set is large and you want to have faster lookups and a more flexible design (what happens if you'll add a column later as your design evolves?), you might consider an in-memory database like [supermodel](https://github.com/maccman/supermodel). That way, you can avoid reinventing the wheel and you gain a lot of functionality and flexibility with very little effort.